# How to fixed the unexpected $EOF in this script?, i've trying to fix but can't

Tags: php, html

How to fixed the unexpected $EOF in this code, i've trying to delete some thing and adding some thing but it not work, i was using google to learn how to fixed it but i not found some thing are work well to my code, this it a code:

```
  <html>
   <head>
    //Head Content
   <head>
   <body>
 SOME HTML CODES
  <?php
  if (!isset($_GET['fburl'])) {
             if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
die('url invalid!');
} else {
function random19() {
  $number = "";
   for($i=0; $i<19; $i++) {
     $min = ($i == 0) ? 1:0;
     $number .= mt_rand($min,9);
 }
  return $number;
}

 echo random19();
 }
        ?>
 </body>
</html> //this it line was unexpected $EOF
```

Comment: Maybe if you correctly formatted your code, you'd see that there's a missing `}`.

Comment: Also, using an editor that highlights curly brace pairs can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clean your code as follows.

```
<html>
  <head>
    //Head Content
 <head>
 <body>

  <?php
    if (!isset($_GET['fburl'])) {
      if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
        die('url invalid!');
      } else {
        echo random19();
      }
    }


 function random19() {
    $number = "";
      for($i=0; $i<19; $i++) {
        $min = ($i == 0) ? 1:0;
        $number .= mt_rand($min,9);
      }
    return $number;
  }

        ?>
 </body>
</html>
```